# AS3: MouseEvent ROLL_OVER/ROLL_OUT Alternatives

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a custom cursor and I want it to change when you highlight a MovieClip, and return to its default value when the MovieClip is not highlighted anymore.

I've used MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, and MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT. The result isn't very smooth and there is a small delay to when the cursor changes. Also sometimes if you move the mouse fast enough the cursor won't change at all.

What are the alternatives to these MouseEvents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handler that does a hit test (can probably use `hitTestPoint` w/ the mouse x/y) on your MoveClip that changes the cursor.